# Universal Covering of $S^1\vee S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm trying to get my head around covering maps and would just like some help with this (probably) rather simple problem. My attempt was to make $\mathbb{R}^2$ a universal covering of $S^1\vee S^2$.

I want to find a universal cover of f $S^1\vee S^2$. My idea was to proceed as follows: Consider $S^1$ as the unit interval quotiented by the equivalence relation $0\sim 1$. Consider the unit sphere $S^2$ as the unit square quotiented by following relation $(0,y)\sim (1,y)$ & $(x,0)\sim (y,0) \forall x,y$ & $(x,1)\sim (y,1) \forall x,y$. I.e as the unit cylinder with top and bottom sides considered as single points.

Now my idea was to join these two objects together and somehow embed them in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to get a universal covering. I'm not sure how to proceed.

I would like to know, (a) is there a way of doing this, (b) is there a better way of doing it, and (c) how we use this to find the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^2$?

Comment: $\mathbb R \cup_{i\in \mathbb Z} S^2$ covers your space, where we glue an $S^2$ to each integer.

Comment: Can you explain why the union has to be infinite? Why can't we just do the same thing with one copy of the sphere?

Comment: You need to have *evenly covered nbhds*, and this cannot be achieved for a nbhd of the gluing point if you include only one sphere (if you're trying to cover your space using a universal cover, that is).

Comment: You can compute $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^2)$ by van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this one asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357810/fundamental-group-and-covering-space-of-gluing-space/2358266), with the Möbius band replaced by the homotopically equivalent (and simpler) $S^1$.

Comment: And if you want to avoid Seifert van-Kampen, you know that $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^2)$ is isomorphic to the group of deck transformations of the universal cover described by Pedro, which is just the group of integer translations of the real line. So $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Imagine a necklace.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: What is the problem with only attaching one copy of $S^2$ to say the origin in $\mathbb{R}$ when constructing the cover? I don't see why this doesn't give you an evenly covered nbhd of the wedge point. I see that you would only get one of course, but I don't see how that contradicts the definition of an evenly covered nbhd. I do see that this means the fibers of the map will have different cardinality which is bad. Maybe I'm not thinking about the covering map correctly and the map does not restrict to a homeomorphism on the nbhd I'm thinking about

Answer (score 2):

As the universal cover contains a subset homeomorphic to $S^2$ it cannot be embedded into $R^2$. But if you want keep the style of your quotient space consider $\mathbb R \times {0} \cup [2n,2n+1] \times [0,1]$ with the equivalence relation $\forall x,y \in [2n,2n+1] \, (x,0)\sim(y,0), (x,1)\sim(y,1)$ and $(2n,x)\sim(2n+1,x)$. This of course looks like $\mathbb R \cup_{i \in Z} S^2$ as Tamaroff suggested.